# Logging buffer size in Rx

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I've got a sequence of Selects on a hot Observable source, and I'm trying to work out which one is 'slowing me down' (i.e. the source has an internal buffer and is telling me that it is having to drop items). And I also want to introduce the possibility of work being done 'in parallel' (i.e. that Transform1 can start work on `item(t + 1)` before Transform2 has finished `item(t)`).

```
source.Select(a => Transform1(a))
      .Select(b => Transform2(a))
      .Select(c => Transform3(a))
```

I've currently got this, which I'm not sure I'd put into production, but at least provides information during development:

```
public static IObservable<T> Buffered<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Action<T, int> log, 
                                                                   IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return Observable.Create<T>(ob =>
    {
        int count = 0;
        return source
            .Do(_ => Interlocked.Increment(ref count))
            .Do(t => log(t, count)) //log on fill
            .ObserveOn(scheduler)
            .Do(_ => Interlocked.Decrement(ref count))
            .Do(t => log(t, count)) //log on empty...
            .Subscribe(ob);
    });
}
```

So my original code becomes:

```
source.Buffered((_, n) => Log($"Transform1 buffer: {n}"))
      .Select(a => Transform1(a))
      .Buffered((_, n) => Log($"Transform2 buffer: {n}"))
      .Select(b => Transform2(a))
      .Buffered((_, n) => Log($"Transform3 buffer: {n}"))
      .Select(c => Transform3(a))
```

And I can see that everything is backing up before Transform2 (for example).

- Am I overlooking something that exists already?
- Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What are you referring to when you say `SelectA` and `SelectB`? There are no selects nor `A`'s or `B`'s in your question. I can't see anything being done in parallel in your code. It's like you've put description and code that don't match each other at all.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I've fleshed it out a bit.

Comment: If you want things to run in parallel with Rx then you should use `SelectMany`, not `Select`. Otherwise just time how long each of your three transforms and work on the slowest one.